# Everything moving up ion view when UIImage doesn't exist

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have designed a UIView where there's an UIImage at the top and under it there's an UILabel. Both of them are populated by JSON and sometimes there won't be an image to load so I want that when this happen, the rest of the stuff in my UIViewController move up so that the space in the picture doesn't exist.

And, actually my image isn't appearing anyway, this is my code:

```
self.imagen.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/img/upload/\(idfoto)")!)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a scroll view on your screen: Unchecking adjust scroll view insets in the inspector may solve your issue.

If not you probably have size constraints that your not noticing. Check the different screen configurations.

Comment: I cannot find that in my attribute inspector

Comment: Select the problematic view controller, open the inspector and navigate to the "Attributes Inspector" tab. It's the first option under the "View Controller > Layout" header.

Comment: I did it but it didn't work, I will check my constraints

Comment: I'm sorry, misread your question. You can make an outlet for the image height constraint, check if you received the image data, and if you did change the constraint value. Finally you need to tell the view controller (maybe self) to update view constraints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102832/discussion-between-marcjames-and-javi-rando).